# how could i pass the checked values of checkbox to next view

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have tried this code.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"next" 
style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(Add:)];



 -(IBAction)Add:(id)sender
 { 
      arr_search=[[search_array alloc]init];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:arr_search animated:YES]; 
}

[MyArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:switchInput]];

[MyAllNoArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
```

is that a right way to perform such tasks?

Comment: it'd be nice to show (in your code that you've listed up there) just how you bring up the next view.

Comment: first define the property in next class where you want to pass the paramter.  and then using 2nd class object where you pass the object send it to that class.

Comment: self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
    initWithTitle:@"next" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain  target:self action:@selector(Add:)];
    
  
}

-(IBAction)Add:(id)sender
{
    
    arr_search=[[search_array alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:arr_search animated:YES];

Comment: please just tell how could i store checked values to the array...

Comment: Please correct the question then. You are trying to ask something else and want something else

Comment: that is what i am asking.
i want to store checkbox checked values to array and then pass that array to next view.
but i dnt know how to do it in right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possibilities for the same.

You can use NSUserDefault to save the status of check box.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:bVal forKey:@"Value"];
```

To get the value use below code:

```
BOOL bGetValue=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Value"];
```

Instead you can also declare property in another class. By creating object of second class and passing parameter to that property u can access the value.

If you want to store value in array of check box is checked or not then do below thing

```
[MyArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",switchInput];
```

To access it,

```
int bVai=[[MyArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
```

//If you want to pass the array to search_array class then do this
//in search_array.h

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *arrVal;
```

//in search_array.m

```
@synthesize arrVal;
```

Now in first view controller

```
[MyArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:switchInput]];

[MyAllNoArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];


-(IBAction)Add:(id)sender
 { 
      arr_search=[[search_array alloc]init];
      arr_search.arrVal=[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
      arr_search.arrVal=MyAllNoArray;
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:arr_search animated:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: thanks buddy.
but i'll not use NSUserDefault
just array.

Comment: this is what i was asking

cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        NSMutableArray *string = [candyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [tempArray addObject:string];

Answer (score 0):

You can set the tag value of your checkboxes when you creates them.

```
NSMutableSet* arrSelectedRow;
    -(IBAction)checkClicked:(UIButton*)sender
    {


        NSNumber* number=[NSNumber numberWithLong:sender.tag];

        if (![arrSelectedRow containsObject:number])
        {


            [arrSelectedRow addObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:sender.tag-300]];//number];
        }
        else
        {


            [arrSelectedRow removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:sender.tag]];
        }

       NSLog(@"Selected row is = %@",arrSelectedRow);
    }
```

Now you can send the arrSelectedRow to nextViewController

Comment: i have not put images of checkbox

Comment: cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        NSMutableArray *string = [candyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [tempArray addObject:string];

this is what i was asking

Answer (score 0):

if
 you are using story board you can paass value from prepareforSegue

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

}
```

or from your Action

```
-(IBAction)Add:(id)sender
{ 
  arr_search=[[search_array alloc]init];

  arr_search.yourVaraible= @"some value"
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:arr_search animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        NSMutableArray *string = [candyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [tempArray addObject:string];
this is code